# ASP.NET Core MVC Error Handling disable default handling

Tags: asp.net-core

I added medleware logind error

```
public class ErrorLoggingMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ErrorLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ErrorLoggingMiddleware> logger) {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        try {
            await _next(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            string user = "", host = "";
            try {
                user = context.User?.Identity.Name;
            } catch {
                user = "Can't get the User!";
            }
            try {
                host = context.Request.Host.ToString();
            } catch {
                host = "Can't get the Host!";
            }
            _logger.LogError($"User='{user}'\r\nHost='{host}'\r\n{e}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Add extension

```
public static class ErrorLoggingMiddlewareExtensions {
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseErrorLogging(this IApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ErrorLoggingMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And call extension method to add midleware

```
       app.UseErrorLogging();
```

SmtpLogger send error succesful, bun I receive two message instead one.

If I comment in middleware throw , then I receive only one message. but then view is empty if error.
How I can disable default error handling and second message about error. Default message like as "Connection ID "18230571306091282804", Request ID "(null)": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application."
I tried to comment many rows in startup file , but nothing helped me.
I don't see call stack default message... and don't understand who call it

Comment: Have you tried looking at the request path, context.Request.Path?

Comment: @RicardoPeres I throw new Exception in Home\Index and this path I see in context.Request.Path

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Development Enviroment . It added microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.exceptionhandlermiddleware and it do additional logging. To resolve this problem need to set Env to Production